# MongoDB live clone

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, replication

I am looking for a way to create a live copy of my mongoDB. My requirement is that this new DB deployment should be completely independent of the existing DB server so, that the access role can be different from the main DB.

My needs are:

- Transfer live data from main DB to this DB as soon as new data is entered
- Main DB should not be accessible from outside network (internet)
- New DB should have only one readOnly user who can read data from internet after authentication (username/password against authenticationDatabase)
- Main DB does not have authentication enabled and it should be as it is

Think of it as if I want to create a mirror of application data without sharing authentication logic. I tried to add new DB in the replica set but it requires same auth policies. Also, I tried creating read-only replica with no voting rights but it did not work as the new DB needs user roles and once the role is added, replication stops as auth fails for internal nodes.

Is there any way to replicate/stream to new DB, so that only application data can be migrated? Also, if there is any other strategy then I can also try that as long as requirement does not change.

Comment: Why do you refuse to enable authentication? It should be **always** enabled.

Comment: You could try mongomirror.

Comment: mclone should do the trick https://github.com/iso8859/mclone